# Seek n number of bits into a file (C++)

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have a file which contains data which is not byte aligned and I want to seek (e.g. 3 bits) into the file and then start reading chars into a buffer. Is there an "easy" way to do this?

I want to avoid bit-shifting each char in the buffer if possible.

Comment: "data which is not byte aligned" how is it possible ?

Comment: You're not going to avoid that which you appear wary of. One way or another, some shifting and masking is on the menu.

Comment: You'll need to talk to hardware manufacturer!

Comment: @Ajay, I am talking with them indeed!  It seem to be the result of problems with their SPI bus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're using a very interesting platform, your file contains bytes. And you read it one byte at a time. So there is no way to do it without bit shifting. The simplest way to **hide** the bit shifting I could think of, is to make an input iterator that stores the previously read byte and does the shift "behind the scenes".

Comment: This is the answer. I was hoping someone knew of a handy little hack. Thanks to Richard Hodges and Marcin Jędrzejewski for nice examples.

Answer (score 0):

[std::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) is specialized on charT to char, which is the smallest chunk of data provided by standard. There is no standard low level way I know of to access files on bit level. You will have to read at least parts of the file and do the analysis in code.

You find on google some std::stream adaptors which will allow for reading bit by bit, but I am not sure if you really need this. One I have found is here: http://stanford.edu/~stepp/cppdoc/ibitstream-class.html

[edit]

Below is a sample reading such file with the use of struct with bitfields:

[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4382deed0b530c99)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // Write test data
    std::vector<bool> bit;
    bit.push_back(0);
    bit.push_back(0);
    bit.push_back(0);

    // Write test byte data, it is padded by 3 bits in front
    for (int n = 0; n < 80 * 13; ++n)
        bit.push_back((n / 8 % 2)==0);

    std::ofstream ofs("test.data", std::ifstream::binary);
    for (auto it = bit.begin(); it != bit.end(); ) {
        char toWrite = 0;
        for (int n = 7; it!=bit.end() && n >= 0; --n, ++it) toWrite |= *it << n;
        ofs.write(&toWrite, 1);
    }
    ofs.close();

    // Read data
    union S {
        struct {
            unsigned short pad : 5;
            unsigned short dat : 8;
            unsigned short oth : 3;
        } inner;
        char bytes[2];
    } data;

    // Create bit vector to verify if reading is correct.
    std::vector<bool> bit2;
    bit2.push_back(0); // First three bits are padding
    bit2.push_back(0);
    bit2.push_back(0);

    std::ifstream ifs("test.data", std::ifstream::binary);
    while(ifs.read(data.bytes, sizeof(data.bytes))) {
        std::swap(data.bytes[0], data.bytes[1]);
        // std::cout << data.inner.dat << ", ";
        for (int n = 7; n >= 0; --n) bit2.push_back(data.inner.dat & (1 << n));
        ifs.seekg(-1, ifs.cur);
    }
    assert(bit == bit2);
}
```

Comment: I beleive, this struct will have size of two bytes. And the poster wants to read data by bytes, but starting from the third bit of the first byte.

Comment: @grisumbras you are right, I have removed that part

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simplistic bit_iterator which wraps a forward_only istream iterator. It allows extraction of individual bits into a word.

It should be enough to get you moving in the right direction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

// forward-only iterator for simplicity
template<class Iter>
struct bit_iterator
{
    using word_type = typename Iter::value_type;
    static constexpr int end_bit = sizeof(word_type) * 8;

    bit_iterator(Iter underlying) : _iter(underlying) {};

    word_type operator*() {
        if (_bitnum == end_bit)
        {
            _word = *_iter++;
            _bitnum = 0;
        }
        auto ret = (_word & (1 << _bitnum++)) ? 1 : 0;
        return ret;
    }

    bit_iterator& operator++() {
        return *this;
    }

    bit_iterator& operator++(int) {
        return *this;
    }

    Iter underlying() const {
        return _iter;
    }

    Iter _iter;
    word_type _word;
    int _bitnum = end_bit;
};

template<class Iter>
auto make_bit_iterator(Iter iter)
{
    return bit_iterator<Iter>(iter);
}

template<class Word, class Iter>
Word get_bits(Iter& iter, size_t bits = sizeof(Word) * 8)
{
    Word acc = 0;
    for ( ; bits ; --bits )
    {
        acc = (acc << 1) | *iter++;
    }
    return acc;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::istringstream is("abcdefghijklmnop");

    auto i = make_bit_iterator(std::istream_iterator<char>(is));

    auto first_three = get_bits<char>(i, 3);

    std::cout << std::hex << int(get_bits<std::uint8_t>(i)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << get_bits<std::int32_t>(i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << get_bits<std::uint16_t>(i) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
32
36313533
3730
```